# S3 - policy and signed policy

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I dont understand what is wrong((

And I have a few questions:

1) If I must put any policy to my S3 bucket. If yes - can you help me understand how to create a policy

2) I have this policy:

```
{
    "expiration": "2016-11-07T20:18:13.326Z",
    "conditions": [
        {
            "acl": "public"
        },
        {
            "bucket": "bucket_name"
        },
        {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        },
        {
            "success_action_status": "200"
        },
        {
            "key": "c94d36ee-19eb-49e8-ac30-760b29982391.txt"
        },
        {
            "x-amz-meta-qqfilename": "111.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

So in my C# code I do :

```
 private string GeneratePolicy()
        {
            byte[] bytesToEncode = File.ReadAllBytes("s3policy.txt");
            string encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesToEncode);
            return encodedText;
        }


  static string GetSig(string policyStr)
        {
            string b64Policy = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(policyStr));

            byte[] b64Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HERE-IS-MY-SECRET-KEY");
            HMACSHA1 hmacSha1 = new HMACSHA1(b64Key);
            string singPolicy = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b64Policy)));
            return singPolicy;
        }
```

But is doesn't work (

Any idea why?

Thank you

Comment: Can you describe exactly what isn't working? Any error messaging to report?

Comment: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Comment: it's not clear from your code or question how this involves fine uploader

Comment: Maybe it is not problem in fine uploader - maybe I do something wrong in policy or how I sign policy - so my question is - WHAT IS WRONG HERE
I think something wrong in 
1) How I sign it - If its correct to use secret key?
2) Or maybe something worng with bucket settings

So I as help guys

Comment: Ok, there is nothing here that appears to be related to Fine Uploader, so I'm going to re-tag. If you can produce some code or information that ties it to Fine Uploader, the tag can be re-added.